# Even if I run headless, I get an "unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary" error

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run Selenium tests in the headless mode in my Jenkins build.
Here is the part of the code where I configure the Chromedriver (yup, many options hahaha):

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920x1080");
chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximised");
chromeOptions.addArguments("enable-automation");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); // I get the error at this line
```

Since I run in headless mode, I expect Jenkins not to go find a Chrome binary. But... it does.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
[... nothing relevant...]
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

Any idea of what I can do?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: without headless they are running ?

Comment: Can you check that? https://www.coveros.com/run-headless-selenium-tests-from-jenkins/
This is a solution that worked for me when I had the same issue.

Comment: @Infern0 yes they are!